# How can I create and run tests on PCL code in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin-studio

This seems relatively simple but I'm not able to find a direct step by step guide anywhere. I have a simple PCL class I've created that is platform independent and I'd like to write a unit test for it. Right now I'm stuck with my test code in an iOS view controller and can only run it by running the app in the simulator. ([Xamarin's documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/touch.unit/) isn't that helpful, as they focus on view testing.)

I've added a new project to my solution by using the `.NET -> Unit Library Project` template. There's a default test in there called Test where I added a failure:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test ()]
        public void TestCase()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("this is a test");
            Assert.Fail ("this should fail");
        }
    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to run this test from within the Xamarin IDE. I'd assume I could right-click on either my new Test project and run the whole thing or right-click on this specific class and run it directly. When I right-click on the Test project, I see the following options:

[image: right-click options on test project]

My Test project structure looks like:

[image: directory structure for test project]

If there's no other option, I would accept an answer that tells me how to run this on the command line.

FWIW, I'm on a Mac running Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9).

Comment: **View** -> **Pads** -> **Unit Tests** will bring up the unit testing window. You should be able to run your tests from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View** -> **Pads** -> **Unit Tests** will bring up the unit testing window: 
[image]

You can run your tests there by clicking **Run All** or by right clicking on a test suite then selecting **Run Test**, **Debug Test** etc:

[image]

[image]